# Resolve Array with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays, ninject, automapper

In Ninject there's automatic implicit self-binding for concrete types. So without further configuration I can resolve every type in my application, like:

```
Foo foo = Kernel.Get(typeof(Foo));
```

Now if I need an Array of `Foo`, how would I do that?

```
Foo[] foos = Kernel.Get(typeof(Foo[])); // does not work
```

EDIT:

For clarification, here is, what I'm actually trying to achieve: In an ASP.NET MVC application I have an AutoMapViewResult (like Jimmy Bogard is talking about in this great(!) video: http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/ or in [ASP.NET MVC  2 in Action](http://manning.com/palermo2/)). The difference is, that I need to inject some service to the constructor of my view model before mapping the entity to it with AutoMapper. If the source type is an array I also must instantiate an array of the view model.

So here finally some (simplified) code :-)

```
public class EventsEditModel
{
    // some properties here
    public Location[] Locations { get; set; }
    public EventsEditModel(ILocationService locationService)
    {
        Locations = locationService.GetAll().ToArray();
    }
}
public class EventsListModel
{
    // some properties here
}
```

and here my AutoMapViewResult:

```
public class AutoMapViewResult : ViewResult
{
    public AutoMapViewResult(object model, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            var viewModel = IoC.Resolve(destinationType);
            ViewData.Model = Mapper.Map(model, viewModel, sourceType, destinationType);
        }
    }
}
```

This works great with `EventsEditModel`. My Index view requires an `EventsListModel[]`, so I need to instantiate an array, which throws a `System.ArgumentNullException`: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source (in the line `var viewModel = IoC...`)

*Note: `IoC.Resolve(Type serviceType)` is just a wrapper for `Kernel.Get(Type serviceType)`*

Comment: First of all, you tell us more about the error than “does not work”.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inject Array of Interfaces in Ninject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102940/inject-array-of-interfaces-in-ninject)

Comment: @Timwi: Sorry for being unclear here. I did not mean, this code doesn't work, but this code is not intended to work. I edited my question to make clearer, what I try to do.

@Ruben: I already read your answer for this question, but I'm not sure if it's really the same. One difference is, that there is an explicit binding while I try to achieve this with the automatic implicit self-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I found some workaround for my AutoMapViewResult. It works but seems a bit like a hack to me... However, here it is:

```
public class AutoMapViewResult<TSource, TDestination> : ViewResult
{
    public AutoMapViewResult(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
    {
        ViewName = viewName;
        MasterName = masterName;

        if (model.GetType().IsArray)
        {
            var viewModel = new List<TDestination>();
            foreach (var item in (TSource[])model)
            {
                viewModel.Add(Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>((TSource)item, IoC.Resolve<TDestination>()));
            }
            ViewData.Model = viewModel.ToArray();
        }
        else if (model.GetType().IsGenericType)
        {
            var viewModel = new List<TDestination>();
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<TSource>)model)
            {
                viewModel.Add(Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>((TSource)item, IoC.Resolve<TDestination>()));
            }
            ViewData.Model = viewModel;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData.Model = Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>((TSource)model, IoC.Resolve<TDestination>());
        }
    }
}
```

The generic parameters `TSource` and `TDestination` describe always sinlge object, not arrays. So to map an array, this is the code to use it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = orderRepository.GetAll();
    return new AutoMapViewResult<Order, OrdersListModel>(null, null, list)
}
```

The AutoMapViewResult then checks, if the model, that is passed to the constructor is an array or a generic list and builds that up.

Comment: Just one note: Thinking about it, I asked myself if it could even be possible for an IoC container return an array, if I don't specify it's length...

Answer (score 0):

Guessing: Did you mean to write this instead?

```
Foo foo = Kernel.Get<Foo>();

Foo[] foos = Kernel.Get<Foo[]>();
```

Comment: I need to use the non-generic Get function because the type is not known at compile time. Have a look at my edited question.