# Ninject Injection of all instances of a generic type with ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, constructor-injection

I would like to be able to use ninject to inject all instances of a particular generic type into a class. For example I have a bunch of custom extractors of a format similar to:

```
public interface IExtract<TEntity> 
{ 
    TEntity ExtractFrom(MyBulkExportedEntity exportedEntity);
}
```

and I want to inject all instances of these extractors into a class responsible for processing this file using ninject multiple binding.

ie

```
public class ProcessDataExtract
{
    /*This isn't valid c# but demonstrates the intent of what i would like to do*/
    public ProcessDataExtract(IEnumerable<IExtract<>> allExtractors)
    {
    }

    public void Process(MyBulkExportedEntity exportedEntity)
    {
        /*loop through all of the extractors and pull relevant data from the object*/
    }
}
```

In the past i have done this by having a management class (IProvideExtractors) which accesses the kernel directly but i don't like this method and was wondering if anyone knows of a better way to do this. With ninject multiple binding I can then get all of the instances im interested in using `kernel.GetAll(typeof(IExtract<>))`

Comment: Inside the `Process` method is it needed for the `IExtract<TEntity>` to be generic? Because if not then I would create a non generic `IExtract` and `IExtract<TEntity>` would inherit from `IExtract`. And with the proper registration in your `ProcessDataExtract` constructor you would depend on `IEnumerable<IExtract> allExtractors`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for something related: I don't wanted to specify all the bindings separately using the Convention extension.

**First:** You need to inject `List<IExtract>` and inherit `IExtract<T> : IExtract` .
This is simply due to the fact, that in C# you can not specify the type of a collection containing different generics. As you noted in your question it is invalid syntax - for a good reason beyond this answer.

You can later pull the elements of `IExtract` out of the list and use reflection to get the generic type paramer and cast it back. Or if you know for what extractor you are looking:

```
public IExtract<T> GetExtractor<T>() {
    return (IExtract<T>)Extractors.Find(e => e is ExtractImpl<T>);
}
```

Now you might have a bunch of classes for that you want some `T` bound to IExtract`.

```
Bind<IExtract>().To<ExtractImpl<MyEntity>>();
Bind<IExtract>().To<ExtractImpl<YourEntity>>();
```

where

```
MyEntity : BaseEntity
YourEntity : BaseEntity
```

You can specify a Convention as following

```
Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom<BaseEntity>()
    .BindWith(new GenericArgumentBindingGenerator(typeof(IExtract<>))));
```

Where `GenericArgumentBindingGenerator` is defind as:

```
public class GenericArgumentBindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    private readonly Type m_Generic;

    public GenericArgumentBindingGenerator(Type generic)
    {
        if (!generic.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("given type must be a generic type definition.", "generic");
        }
        m_Generic = generic;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        if (bindingRoot == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingRoot");
        if (type.IsAbstract || type.IsInterface)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>>();
        }

        var bindings = new List<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>>();
        IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object> binding = bindingRoot
            .Bind(typeof(IExtract)) // you maybe want to pass typeof(IExtract) to constructor
            .To(m_Generic.MakeGenericType(type));

        bindings.Add(binding);

        return bindings;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this binding generator it seems pretty cool, also i think you are right extending off a non-generic would solve this issue in terms of binding

Comment: What is IEnvironmentConfigFile to be replaced it?

Comment: Oh damn I missed one - got it from my code ;) IEnvironmentConfigFile would be IExtract I guess. But it should be passed through the constructor of GenericArgumentBindingGenerator  to make it generic. you acutally want to bind `Bind<IExtract>().To<ExtractImpl<YourEntity>>();` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this seems to be that there isnt a way of doing this with ninject

Comment: There are some workarounds in [Inject Array of Interfaces in Ninject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102940/inject-array-of-interfaces-in-ninject).

Answer (score 1):

**Option A**

I'm pretty sure you can do this:

```
public class ProcessDataExtract
{
    public ProcessDataExtract<TExtract>(IEnumerable<IExtract<TExtract>> allExtractors)
    {
    }
    ...etc...
}
```

And then list out your bindings in your binding module's `Load` method:

```
...
Bind<IExtract<TEntity>>().To<SomeConcreteExtract>();
Bind<IExtract<TEntity>>().To<AnotherConcreteExtract>();
Bind<IExtract<TEntity>>().To<YetAnotherConcreteExtract>();
...
```

And NInject will deliver them to your constructor that advertises a dependency on a bunch of them.  I've done that in the past with success.

**Option B**

Change

```
public interface IExtract<TEntity> 
{ 
    TEntity ExtractFrom(MyBulkExportedEntity exportedEntity);
}
```

to

```
public interface IExtract
{ 
    TEntity ExtractFrom<TEntity>(MyBulkExportedEntity exportedEntity);
}
```

Which would allow:

```
        public ProcessDataExtract<TExtract>(IEnumerable<IExtract<TExtract>> allExtractors)
    {
    }
    ...etc...
```

to be:

```
    public ProcessDataExtract(IEnumerable<IExtract> allExtractors)
    {
    }
    ...etc...
```

And the NInject bindings would be adjusted, too:

```
...
Bind<IExtract>().To<SomeConcreteExtract>();
Bind<IExtract>().To<AnotherConcreteExtract>();
Bind<IExtract>().To<YetAnotherConcreteExtract>();
...
```

Comment: Yeah so in ninject there is a concept of injecting all instances of a binding which is what i would like to leverage. You can do this directly from ninject with the above instance using `kernel.GetAll(typeof(IExtract<>))` which will return an `IEnumerable<object>` containing all of my extractors. My problem isnt with this, my problem is that i cant work out how to specify this in my constructor, as the above code isnt valid C#

Comment: I corrected the syntax.  You'll be stuck with just one conrete `TExtract`, however.  Which would need to be a non-generic base class (abstract or not). Or you could push the type parameter from `IExtract` to the `ExtractFrom`, which would take the homogeneity away from `ProcessDataExtract`.  I'll add what I mean into my answer.

Comment: I suppose what your saying is I could use `Enumerable<IExtract<object>> allExtractors`, im pretty sure this isnt possible as i dont think `typeof(IExtract<object>).IsAssignableFrom(tyepof(IExtract<MyConcreteEntity>))` see https://compilify.net/1tj

Comment: To make your reflection life easier, use a naming convention for the concrete `IExtract` classes that encodes the `TEntity` so that you don't have to the loop each time you add a new one.

Comment: that seems like a bit of a hack to get around the issue though, surely there is a more elegant solution